# Upload two different Laravel projects on the CPanel, connected to the same database

Tags: cpanel, laravel-6

I'm trying to upload two Laravel projects connected to the same database on the CPanel, the two URLs worked perfectly on the browser but both of them display only one project for the two routs.
I have written the same user and password of the database to both projects
I didn't know what is the problem...

Comment: you have to post codes. or errors.

Comment: are they on same url?
example, `first.yourdomain.com` and then `second.yourdomain.com`? or???

Comment: yes the same @hasan05

Comment: you mean, you have to project. and one url like `yourdomain.com`. and you want to run both project on that?

Comment: yes they are exactly like first.yourdomain.com and second.yourdomain.com
each url should display different project @hasan05

Comment: did you checked your cpanel subdomains file path? are they okay as you wants?

Comment: yes, I have only one subdomain, the other one is the main domain @hasan05

Comment: If your subdomains document is on proper folder direction then, may be the problem is on htaccess.

Comment: what about the htaccess? @hasan05

Comment: If you create subdomain, then, htaccess should be updated. better you check your `subdomain` and `document root` from subdomain portion. by the way, this problem is not laravel issue, it is cpanel issue.

Comment: okay, I have no idea what should I do, but thank you anyway @hasan05